# What is the recommended way to run Bot Dispatcher for Production chatbot?

Tags: botframework

We have a chatbot on production which uses Bot Dispatcher to combine multiple LUIS and QnA maker. The way I know to refresh a dispatcher is to run a command "dispatch refresh" in command prompt. However, we cannot ask a customer to run the command in command prompt manually rather we would like to give them some link where this can be done from a website once they do any change in QnA knowledge base.

I was trying to build a website in Dotnet core to execute the dispatch refresh command on server using a process execute but couldn't succeed yet as the application fails to run the command when runs on IIS. Below is my code -

```
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Startup.RootPath;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "dispatch refresh";
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
```

I just want to understand is there any other good way to refresh the dispatcher other than running the command manually on server?

Comment: What is the error during the failure? Is the .dispatch file in the Startup.RootPath location? Maybe having some sort of daemon/service run that would check for a 'run flag' that is set somewhere. And just have your website be point that sets that run flag.

Comment: You might try adding the `--remote true` switch. Check out [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/issues/1474#issuecomment-703876630).